# Move div with dynamic height out of its parent container

Tags: html, css, height, overflow

I'm trying to move a div with a dynamically changing height out of it's parent div and back in.

The problem is the dynamically height, otherwise I could easily set the negative height as the bottom value.
For now I just set a large negative number of pixels as the bottom value, but it isn't very nice and does not solve the problem properly. (logically this happens for small numbers: [**fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/k5uy0ayn/))
Hopefully the example below clarifies what I try to do.

I was thinking about using *transforms* instead, but i did not find a solution as well.

Of course I could do this with JavaScript, but as everyone **I prefer a pure CSS solution** :)

```css
#outer {
    position: relative;
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    background: black;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#inner {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -500px;
      /*
        It's working but ugly and not perfect.
        The value I need would be the height of the inner div, but it is dynamic
      */
    width: 100%;
    background: red;
    transition: 0.4s;
}

#outer:hover #inner {
    transition: 0.4s;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
    <div id="inner">
        Some expanding text here
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use CSS `transform:translateY(100%)` property, so the height is calculated based on the element itself. Then reset the value to `0` on hover.

Inspect the element, you'll be able to see exact the height and position of it.

Also take a look of [support tables](http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d) for `transform`, and prefix it if necessary.

**[Updated JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k5uy0ayn/4/)**

```css
.outer {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: grey;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.inner {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background: aqua;
    transition: 0.4s;
    transform: translateY(100%);
}
.outer:hover .inner {
    bottom: 0;
    transform: translateY(0);
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">Some expanding text here..</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I also had this idea, but I wasn't sure which value the -100% represents and it seems to act like a large number of pixels. (which you can see at the different transition in-out speed)

Comment: @Robbendebiene You're right on that. I updated the answer and it's been corrected.

Comment: Wow this looks pretty good :) I'm just not sure which number the 100% represents, but it looks like it is the height of the inner div?

Comment: @Robbendebiene it is the 100% of the element height that is set to transform.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your issue, you can set a `max-height` for its normal and `:hover` state and transition it. However, you must set it to a `max-height` that you know will always be tall enough (which may lead to random speeds depending on how much content there is).

So something like:  [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k5uy0ayn/2/)

```
.outer {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    background: black;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.inner {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    background: red;
    transition: 0.4s;
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;

}
.outer:hover .inner {
    transition: 0.4s;
    bottom: 0;
    max-height: 40px;
}
```

Otherwise, I would recommend a JS solution.

Comment: Very nice idea, the only problem is that the transition effect is using the `max-height` to calculate the animation speed. Due to that the slide animation gets very fast for a large number like `100px` for `max-height`.

Comment: Right, I mentioned that speeds can vary in the answer.